# Highlight text, drop it and open new tab url

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to open new tab by highlighting text and dropping it in a div, that uses function to create a new variable with the dropped text, and open new tab with the new variable.
I have found some sources that can do that with a paste from clipboard.

here is [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c5v6ptwa/)

```
function handlePaste (e) {
        var clipboardData, pastedData;

        // Stop data actually being pasted into div
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();

        // Get pasted data via clipboard API
    clipboardData = e.clipboardData || window.clipboardData;
    pastedData = clipboardData.getData('Text');
    window.open('http://'+pastedData+'.com', '_blank');
    }

document.getElementById('editableDiv').addEventListener('paste', handlePaste);
```

Comment: See https://jsfiddle.net/c5v6ptwa/1/

Comment: Thank you tewathia, but i would like to drag any text, like from note pad etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to modify it like this:

```
function handlePaste (e) {
    var clipboardData, pastedData;

    // Stop data actually being pasted into div
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();

    // Get pasted data via clipboard API
    clipboardData = e.clipboardData || window.clipboardData;
    pastedData = clipboardData.getData('Text');
    window.open('http://'+pastedData+'.com', '_blank');
}

document.getElementById('editableDiv').addEventListener('paste', handlePaste);

// Store dragged element
document.addEventListener("dragstart", function( event ) {
    // store a ref. on the dragged elem
    dragged = event.target;
}, false);

// Drop event listener
document.getElementById('editableDiv').addEventListener('drop', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();

    // dragged element (p tag) is a DOM node, so we have to take it's text content
    window.open('http://'+dragged.textContent+'.com', '_blank');
});
```

### [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/c5v6ptwa/2/)